# How do I turn an array into a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var beasts = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234';

function countAllBeasts(antMany) {

  var OrigString = antMany.split(', ');

  for (var i = 0; i < OrigString.length; i++){
    var justAnt = OrigString[i];
   ;
    if (OrigString.startsWith('CJ') === true){
      (justAnt.length);

    }
  }
  var forLoop = justAnt[i];
  console.log(forLoop);

  return justAnt;
};
```

update: I still want to use a for loop as the section requires it and it is more simple than other methods. Hoping for the least amount of change to provide the number of the ant xxx in the string that would result after splitting, running in a for loop, and sorting by ant using startsWith... I know there are other approaches but I am looking for the simplest. I was not clear about it before but am clear about it now.

Answer (score 2):

**With Regexp you can accomplish that with only one line of code.**

```
// This will return 4 matches (4 commas) + 1 = count of blocks separated by comma.
new RegExp("\,", "g")
```

```js
let count = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234'.match(new RegExp("\,", "g")).length + 1;
console.log(count);
```

**According to your approach:**
*Using a basic `for-loop`*

```js
function countAllBeasts(antMany) {
  var origString = antMany.split(', ');
  var ants = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < origString.length; i++) {
    if (origString[i].startsWith('ant'))
       ants.push(origString[i]);
  }
  
  return ants;
}

var beasts = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234';
console.log(countAllBeasts(beasts));
```

You can accomplish that using function `filter`

```js
function countAllBeasts(antMany) {
  var origString = antMany.split(', ');
  var ants = origString.filter((block) => block.trim().startsWith('ant'));

  return ants;
}

var beasts = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234';
console.log(countAllBeasts(beasts));
```

Comment: This is a great answer but I was specifically using a for loop. I should have stated that, but I'm working on an exercise that requests the use of a for loop.

Comment: @Jackal21 Right!, Well, I'm going to keep that answer to help anyone else :-)

Comment: Can you help me make my code run? Since you're so smart? I would appreciate it so much. I have added the answer below.

Comment: @Jackal21 take the code of your answer below and paste it into your question, and remove that answer :-).

Comment: I dont think you are just counting antxxx, or are you? It seems like you are counting all of the items?

Comment: I'm only counting the `andxxx` using `startsWith('ant')`.

Answer (score 1):

There are already builtin functions for that.

Use a [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to create an array, using comma as separator, then count the number of elements in the array with [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```js
var beasts = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234';
var beastsArray = beasts.split(',');
console.log(beastsArray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split using `split` function. It will return an array. You dont need to push using for loop to a separate array.

```
var beasts = 'ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, goose 234';
var array = beasts.split(",");
console.log(array.length); // Prints 5 in the console
```

Comment: Thats a great answer but then it would count both ant 222, bison, ant 333, ant 555, and goose 234. I want it to only count ant 222, ant 333 and ant 555  and by count I mean give me a number; in this case that would be 3.

Comment: Then you can split using a regular expression.You can achieve it with for loop also. I prefer regular expression